# Is it possible to create and use sequence generator in JPA / Hibernate without a column?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, sequence

I'm using JPA (Hibernate) and I want to create a sequence for example like this.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999
  START 1;
```

This sequence shouldn't be assigned to a special column or table. I just want to be able to query the next value:

```
  SELECT nextval('my_seq')
```

By doing this I would have a nice possibility to generate unique ids for anything i like.

Btw: I'm using Hibernate 4.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: Use a SQL query. Done. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: for querying this is ok but also for creation?

Comment: You will need SQL scripts or database setup/migration tools at some point (like FlywayDB or Liquibase). I would use them right away rather than relying on Hibernate to do that.

Comment: I already use Liquibase and I'm happy with it but I would like to keep the possibility to change persistence.xml to create.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {
  @SequenceGenerator(name="Event_Seq", sequenceName="Event_Seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Event_Seq")
  @Id
  private Long id;
}
```

You can create `Event_Seq` by script or leave it for Hibernate to create (provided you are using schema generation). You also need DB that is supporting sequences.

Comment: I don't want to create a separat entity just to use a sequence.

Comment: You don't have to. It was just an example.